# Coredata Delete Parent record when there is no children in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift5, cascade

I have an **AlbumDB**(Parent) and **SongInfoDB**(Children's). When there no children's then I need to remove a parent as well means AlbumDB.

[image]

Here in the image, I need to remove **AlbumDB** when there is no **SongInfoDB**. In other words, when I remove all **songs** then automatically **album** will be removed.

I checked some of StackOverflow link and try core data delete rule as well.
Nullify, Cascade, Deny but none of these worked for me!

Is there any suggestion regarding this. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic way. You can delete children automatically if the parent object was deleted but not vice versa.

A posible solution is to create a function which deletes the song, then checks if the album (the relationship) is empty and if so deletes also the album.

Something like

```
func deleteSong(_ song : Song) {
    context.delete(song)
    let album = song.album!
    if album.songs.isEmpty {
        context.delete(album)
    }
    context.save()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Here, In songs, Should I select delete rule to cascade?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, it deletes all attached songs when an album is deleted.