# Issue deleting records from one to many relationship Core Data | Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

Essentially I have a one to many relationship between 2 Core Data entities, one country to many candies. What kind of function/calculation would let me delete a record from the candies entity? If the last candy is delete from a country the country must also get deleted.

[image]

Currently adding records like this:

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var countries: FetchedResults<Country>

Button("Add Examples") {
  let candy1 = Candy(context: moc)
  candy1.name = "Mars"
  candy1.orgin = Country(context: moc)
  candy1.orgin?.shortName = "UK"
  candy1.orgin?.fullName = "United Kingdom"
}
```

What would an onDelete action be in this scenario?

```
.onDelete(perform: //)
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66105864/coredata-delete-parent-record-when-there-is-no-children-in-swift-5

Comment: How do you select the Candy object to delete? Basically you can just delete it with `mom.delete(candyObject)`.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to first delete your candy and then put condition to last candy is delete from a country the country also get deleted.**

```
func deleteCandyAndCountry(_ candy : Candy) {
   do {
        try context.delete(candy)
        let country = candy.country!
        if country.candy.isEmpty {
           try context.delete(country)
        }
        try context.save()
   catch {
        print("Can't Delete your candy with Country")
   }
}
```